# sync or async for waitforexistence in XCTest?

Tags: swift, xctest, xcuitest

I am new to XCTest and see the following code but get one question about [waitforexistence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence)

```
if aXCUIElement.waitforexistence(timeout: 60) || bXCUIElement.waitforexistence(timeout: 60) {
}
```

in this case, are we waiting for one minutes to see if aXCUIElement or bXCUIElement exists? or we are waiting for one min for aXCUIElement then waiting for another 1 mins for bXCUIElement?

Comment: The latter, the function is synchronous and an OR statement is evaluated from left to right.

Comment: if the function is synchronous. so it should only wait for 60s right?